# apt-get update, unlinking

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 16.04

I've recently moved to xenial ubuntu. After upgrading, I was no more able to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The output is the following:

```
Get:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease [247 kB]
Hit:2 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates  InRelease             
Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com xenial InRelease                            
Hit:6 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                           
Fetched 247 kB in 0s (307 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
W: Problem unlinking the file backup - Clean (21: Is a directory)
```

I've tried googling for this particular problem but with no success.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found a solution to this :)
Here you can find a similar issue: "[Thread: Problems with software upgrading: aptdaemon](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1914808)".

The problem arises from the following directory:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/partial
```

So doing the following:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
sudo apt-get update
```

did the trick :)